# Why scanf("%c\n") have a delay in stdin

Tags: c, stdin, scanf

Well , I know there are lots of question about `scanf`, but I still want to ask. I hope someone can explain the rules or principle for this issue:

code first:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main()
   {
           int c = 'W';
           while(c != 'F'){

                   scanf("%c",&c);
                   printf("c is : %c\n",c);
           }
           return 0;
   }
```

And here is the output:

```
E
c is : E
c is :                  <--newline

G
c is : G
c is :                  <---newline again

W
c is : W
c is :                  <---newline 

F
c is : F
```

Well, I still can understand by now, for the newline I input stay in buffer and assignment c  every time after alphabet a press.So , I try code2:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

   int main()
   {
           int c = 'W';
           while(c != 'F'){

                   scanf("%c\n",&c);   //<-- the only modified place.
                   printf("c is : %c\n",c);
          }
          return 0;
  }
```

Then I get this screen:

```
E
G                        <---why the input and has one step before the output? 
c is : E         
W
c is : G
S
c is : W
C
c is : S
F
c is : C
R                       <---R was left in stdin, turn to a garbage, I didn't hope this. 
c is : F
```

I also have try to flush the `stdin` and `stdout`, still no use.

*Note* : I know if use `scanf("%c",c);`and another `scanf("%c",&d);` behind to deal with `'\n'` can fixed this, I just confuesed ,**I hope to understand why the code2's issue happened.**

I have check the answer before but I am not a really careful man , if this answer is really duplicate ,all downvote can be understand. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you would probably be better off using simply `scanf("%c ",&c)`, which will skip past any and all trailing whitespace.

Comment: When one uses `\n` at the format end of `scanf()`, its time to consider`fgets()` & `scanf()` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Passing any combination of consecutive white-space to scanf (including space, tab and new-lines, no matter what) means "read until first non-whitespace is occurred" (including EOF).

In your **second** example scanf reads the 'E', reads newline and still waits for non-whitespace to appear.

Comment: "*In your second example scanf reads the 'E', reads newline and still waits for non-whitespace to appear.*", you should specify that this statement is only true for his **second** example.

Answer (score 2):

So `stdin` (on your system definitely, and generally) is line-buffered, meaning that no input reaches the program until you hit "enter". This means that the program itself doesn't have to deal with "backspace" and such things.

When you use `"%c\n"`, `scanf` is accepting a newline only after the input. If that's not there, it gets ignored.

As suggested in the comment, `"%c "` will skip "any whitespace" (newline, tab, space and formfeed, I believe, counts as "whitespace"). But you still aren't guaranteed to read "any input" as one character without something going in as the "unwanted input". `scanf` is definitely not great for reading human entered input. It is good for reading machine generated data, because it's flexible and can handle a bunch of different format, but for humans that type the wrong thing, etc, it's not that great. Either use `fgets()` (and perhaps `sscanf` to then parse the input, but at least you don't get "some stuff the user typed for this line, is left waiting to be read next time round" type of surprise"  or use low-level, system dependent input functions, or a library like `ncurses`.

Comment: `"%c "` has no use , for newline. I have tryed.

Comment: Like I said, it probably doesn't help much. `scanf` is simply not good for "human input".

Answer (score 2):

"\n" in scanf doesn't mean that a newline character is expected. You can find the explanation here: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfhang.html

Answer (score 1):

For the first example it's because `scanf` reads one character at a time from `stdin`. Since it does that, in terminal you will need to enter a whitespace character for `scanf` to begin extracting from the stream. So it looks like you are entering the following sequence:

```
E, (new line), G, (new line), ...
```

... and hence the output will be as it is in your example.

Similarly for your second example except you are reading in a character followed by a newline (`scanf( "%c\n" )` as oppose to just a character -- however same reasoning.

**Remark:**

If you piped it the following text file:

```
EGJKF
```

... then it would have the output you expected:

```
c is : E
c is : G
c is : J
c is : K
c is : F
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe yeputons has provided the best explanation of the behaviour you're seeing, but to solve your actual problem (which surprisingly I didn't find on StackOverflow already), see this post: http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps012a/Fall98/faq/scanfQ.html

It suggests using `scanf("%*[ \n\t]%c",&c);`, which will skip all whitespace before the character. By skipping whitespace before instead of after the character, you're not left waiting on further input.

Comment: Would not a simpler `scanf(" %c",&c)` accomplish the same?  BTW: `[ \n\t]` are not _all_ whitespace character, but certainly common ones.

Comment: @chux I think that's the point: maybe the user is intentionally sending (say) a vertical tab. Depending on the use, you might even want to allow tab and space. But I'm posting it as a quote of the source. If I were to write it, I would do as you say and use a standard space (unless I had a special requirement)

Answer (score 0):

there is NOTHING wrong with `scanf`, when used appropriately.

For this problem try using a format of `"%1s"` and point c to a char field of length two and test c[0] for data.

The idea is that `%s` is more cognizant of white space.